# OpenCV cv::imshow() GUI not showing

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to display an image, where it is crucial to be able to zoom in.
On my Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 machine, the GUI always shows and the image is zoomable.

But on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, the GUI never shows and is not zoomable. I've tried the following ways to create the Window:

```
cv::namedWindow("Name", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::namedWindow("Name", CV_GUI_NORMAL);
cv::namedWindow("Name", CV_GUI_EXTENDED);
```

using the `cv::namedWindow()` and the `cvNamedWindow()` commands. They all work on my 16.04 machine, yet none on my 18.04.

My OpenCV Version is 3.2 and I'm using it in a ROS workspace if that makes any differences.

Comment: Do you have the libraries installed in the OS?

Comment: You have to call `waitKey()` to draw it

Comment: With with library was compiled OpenCV? In CMAKE: Qt, GTK or GTK_2_x?

Comment: Yes, I did call `waitKey()`. I am sorry if i put this wrong: my problem is not, that the image doesn't show. The image does show, it's just not zoomable. I'm compiling using CMAKE but i don't know with wich library it is compiled. Any suggestions where I can find this information?

Comment: Does the program keep running? Because after it returns, I think zooming is not possible anymore.

Comment: It kind of does. I open the window inside a Constructor but keep a mouse Callback. It does, however, zoom on another machine with ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the flags you are using might be outdated. As in the documentation of [OpenCV 3.2.0](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5afdf8410934fd099df85c75b2e0888b), usable flags are as follows:

- **WINDOW_NORMAL** or **WINDOW_AUTOSIZE**: WINDOW_NORMAL enables you to resize the window, whereas WINDOW_AUTOSIZE adjusts automatically the window size to fit the displayed image (see imshow ), and you cannot change the window size manually.
- **WINDOW_FREERATIO** or **WINDOW_KEEPRATIO**: WINDOW_FREERATIO adjusts the image with no respect to its ratio, whereas WINDOW_KEEPRATIO keeps the image ratio.

These flags might work for you.